# How to delete specific row table using an onClick function in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to delete a certain specific row using DOM?

and the problem in **/line10** when I press the X button it keeps deleting the first row.

The code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HamzaSamiHussein1_/6jbz8tex/latest/)

```
function render(){
 for (let i = 0; i < allMovie.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("id", "mainTR");
    table.appendChild(tr);

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.textContent = allMovie[i].MovieName11;
    td1.setAttribute("class", "td1");
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.textContent = allMovie[i].selectPlatform11;
    td2.setAttribute("class", "td2");
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td3.textContent = allMovie[i].randomRate;
    td3.setAttribute("class", "td3");
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    var td4 = document.createElement('td');
    td4.textContent = allMovie[i].monthlyPay11;
    td4.setAttribute("class", "td4");
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    var td5 = document.createElement('td');
    td5.setAttribute("id", "td5");
    td5.innerHTML = `<button onclick=remove()> X </button>`
    tr.appendChild(td5);
}
}

function remove() { /line10
  var removeOBJ = document.getElementById("mainTR");
  return removeOBJ.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `this.`[parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and pass as an args in your `remove()` function to remove the clicked `tr` element from the table.

Also `id` needs to be `unique` for every element so consider using `class` instead to avoid issues.

```
tr.setAttribute("class", "mainTR"); //use class attr for tr elements
```

Remove function

```
function remove(element) {
    element.parentNode.remove(element); //remove the clicked tr
}
```

**Live Working Demo**

```js
var allMovie = [];
var selectArr = ['netflix', 'Amazon Prime video', 'HBO', 'Hulu', 'Apple TV Plus', 'Disney Plus', 'Crunchyroll'];
var selectPlatform = document.getElementById('select-platform');
var table = document.getElementById('table');

for (let i = 0; i < selectArr.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = selectArr[i];
  selectPlatform.appendChild(option);
}

var form1 = document.getElementById('form');
form1.addEventListener('submit', addfun);

function addfun() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log(event)

  new Movie(event.target[0].value, event.target[1].value, event.target[3].value);
  clearTable();
  render();

  // set();

}
//get();
render();
clearTable();
render();


/*Constructor*/
function Movie(MovieName, selectPlatform, monthlyPay) {
  this.MovieName11 = MovieName;
  this.selectPlatform11 = selectPlatform;
  this.monthlyPay11 = monthlyPay * 13.99;
  this.randomRate = generateRandomRate(100, 10);
  allMovie.push(this);
}


function render() {
  for (let i = 0; i < allMovie.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("class", "mainTR");
    table.appendChild(tr);

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.textContent = allMovie[i].MovieName11;
    td1.setAttribute("class", "td1");
    tr.appendChild(td1);

    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.textContent = allMovie[i].selectPlatform11;
    td2.setAttribute("class", "td2");
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td3.textContent = allMovie[i].randomRate;
    td3.setAttribute("class", "td3");
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    var td4 = document.createElement('td');
    td4.textContent = allMovie[i].monthlyPay11;
    td4.setAttribute("class", "td4");
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    var td5 = document.createElement('td');
    td5.setAttribute("id", "td5");
    td5.innerHTML = `<button onclick=remove(this.parentNode)> X </button>`
    tr.appendChild(td5);
  }
}

//Remove tr
function remove(element) {
  element.parentNode.remove(element);
}

//helper function:- 
function generateRandomRate(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function clearTable() {
  table.innerHTML =
    `
    <tr>
    <td>Movie Name</td>
    <td>Favourite streaming platform</td>
    <td>Movie Rate</td>
    <td>Your pay monthly on Streaming platforms</td>
    </tr>
    `
}

function set() {
  var sendJSON = JSON.stringify(allMovie);
  localStorage.setItem('allMovie', sendJSON)
}

function get() {
  var getJSON = localStorage.getItem('allMovie');
  if (getJSON) {
    allMovie = JSON.parse(getJSON)
  }

}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h3>
    Streaming platforms price per month is :- <mark>13.99$</mark>

  </h3>
  <form id="form">
    <label>Movie/series Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="input-form">

    <label>Select your favourite streaming platform</label>
    <select id="select-platform">

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">

    <label>Enter how many platforms you watch from(max 7)</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="7">
  </form>

  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Movie Name</td>
      <td>Favourite streaming platform</td>
      <td>Movie Rate</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- <td>You pay monthly on streaming platforms</td> -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is parentNode mean?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI `parentNode` means the parent of the current node. Means the `td` (button is inside the td) - we will send that as an arguments to the `remove()` function. and in the function `element.parentNode` means the parent - actual `tr` which is holding that whole row. You can also read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Comment: How to connect it with localStorage?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI I am not sure what you mean by that. An HTML element and localStorage are two different. localStorage is where you save data and retrieve data.

Comment: Is there another site that I can chat with regarding this topic, I mean if we can shareScreen using zoom for example?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI I would suggest reading the docs to get clear picture on localStorage and its usage. [Here is the question you can read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) more about localStorage. Also, to saved your table data (i am guessing that what you want to do) you need to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to `setItem` and `getItem`

Comment: yes, I know how to do that, but as you can see when I delete it, deletes the row, but the whole table elements return when I press the submit button again.

Comment: @HamzaSAMI Its because you are getting and storing the `data` from array `allMovie`. .remove function only removes the HTML element from the DOM. You need to use array `splice` method to remove that element from the allMovie array as well. I would suggest posting a question separately So that someone can help you properly. Its a total separate question. Thanks

Comment: but to be clear, I will not use localStorage to add this feature to the webpage, right?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI Yes correct. they are two different things.

Comment: @HamzaSAMI Always happy to help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the same id for every row

```
tr.setAttribute("id", "mainTR");
```

so this is invalid as an id must be unique, therefore your dom-selection returns only the first occurance

you could append for example the index of the loop to make it unique

Comment: how to do that, can you give me an example